# Use CharField choices not only in admin

Tags: django, django-models

I've got a model with a property which represents the current status of something.

```
STATUSES = (('status1', 'The first status'),('status2', 'The second status'),('status3', 'The third status'))
status = models.CharField(choices=STATUSES)
```

When using Django-Admin, the choices (i.e. "The first status") is displayed instead of the values (i.e "status1"). How can i achieve this when printing out the status in one of my templates? Or is there any better model field to use in this case?

I know I could just use the same string in both elements in the tuples in `STATUSES`, but this seems like quite bad practice and makes it hard to rename choices if needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To display the human readable version of the currently selected choice, use:

`{{ instance.get_myfield_display }}`

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display